# Should recursive shell script lock up the system?

Tags: system, scripts

I made a typo and ran my shell script recursively. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# filename: kill-me-please.sh   
./kill-me-please.sh
```

This caused my system to become unresponsive and all I could do was a hard restart.

Tried same on MacOS and it was able to detect this problem and terminated the script with an error.

I think an operating system should be able to handle such a situation. Is this a bug?

Comment: To all close-voters: Please comment what's wrong before submitting your votes. This question was valid and only phrased badly. A small edit and it's "constructive" again.

Comment: @Glutanimate I know how to prevent it. So I think your edit is wrong. My question was "is this a bug?". Can you please revert?

Comment: @umpirsky add in how you would prevent it and then the focus comes to the "is this a bug?"  (the 2nd Q can then be deleted).

Comment: @umpirsky Alright, sorry for that then. I think it would be helpful though to include the measures you would take to prevent this from happening (aside from avoiding recursions in the first place). Just as Rinzwind pointed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have done can be called a [*fork bomb*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).  A fork bomb is a shell script, or a single shell command that calls itself recursively, and thus fills up all the system resources.  Rather than a bug, this is a [DoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack.

Every time `./kill-me-please.sh` is executed, a new process is created, using some memory and clock cycles.  Your program is capable of creating infinitely many forks of itself, but because the system resources are finite, at some point on time, you'll run out of resources.  There are many kinds of fork bombs which exploit this possibility.  Another well-known example is:

```bsh
$ :(){ :|:& };:
```

Here `:` is the name of a shell function.  In the function, the `:` is recursively called two times in a subshell.  This will have the same affect as your script.

*Defusing* these fork bombs is hard, as all the resources might get exploited by the fork bomb until you find and apply the necessary routine.  Some ways of recovery are explained and discussed in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb#Defusing).

To prevent this, on Linux and possibly other [Unices](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnixClones), one can use [`ulimit`](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) utility to limit the number of processes that a user can create. `ulimit -Hu 50` will hard-limit user to 50 processes (so user won't be able to change it). Also on many systems there are configuration files that can be used to set this kind of limits.

Chances are your OS X system already has a process limit set.  I can think of other ways to prevent this, but I can't say neither my ideas are valid solutions nor they are implemented by any operating system, so, I'll keep them to myself.  Possibly many people reading this thread will think about same possibilities anyway.